# Mysql. Почему запрос выводит только одну строку из таблицы?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT surname_Student, name_Student, fathername_Student, dob_Student, number_Class, attribute_Class 
FROM Students 
JOIN Class ON id_Class = id_Student 
WHERE number_Class =1 and attribute_Class ='A';
```

[image: Изображение из бд]

В таблице две строки, но по данному запросу выводит только первую строку. Можете подсказать почему?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: *`.. ON id_Class = id_Student ..`* Серьёзно? Идентификатор класса равен идентификатору студента?

Comment: Таблицу Class предоставьте, пожалуйста...

Comment: CREATE TABLE Class (id _Class INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, number _Class INT, attribute_Class VARCHAR(30), teacher _Class INT, FOREIGN KEY (teacher _Class) REFERENCES Teachers (id_Teachers) );

В таблице класс только одна строка 
id_Class = 1
number_Class = 1
attribute_Class = "A'
teacher_Class = 1

Comment: Вы лучше напишите, что вы хотите сделать и что не получается, а не то, что делаете. То что запрос работает не так как вам хотелось бы, вовсе не означает, что он работает неправильно.

Comment: Что у вас хранится в поле "class_Student" ? P.s. Именование полей ужасное.